# Filter numatched query Left join on access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is scenario. In this inventory management system , there are items. Items can be composed and make composed items. Eg. Monitor, system unit, keyboard, mouse can be composed to A1 (composed item)

When I assign item to Composed Item , I used combo box to generate items and select the items. Then I want to narrow combo box generation to only item that not in composed items. ( for eg. Mouse m1 is assigned to composed item A1. Then again I don't want to see it from my combo box) I made following unmatched query to filter out items.

```
SELECT Item.ITEMID, Item.SN, Item.TYPE, Item.BRAND,
       Item.LOCATION, Item.COMMENCEDDATE, Item.CONDEMNDATE,
       Type.TypeName
FROM Type INNER JOIN
     (Item LEFT JOIN
      ComposedIItem
      ON Item.[ITEMID] = ComposedIItem.[ITEMID]
     )
     ON Type.TYPEID = Item.TYPE
WHERE (((ComposedIItem.ITEMID) Is Null) XOR 
       (((ComposedIItem.ITEMID) Is Not Null) AND
       ((ComposedIItem.DETACHEDDATE) Is Not Null))
      );
```

Of course there is a situation that a item can be detached from composed item and later it can be again assigned to composed items.

In snapshot you can find my workings.

The sql works well till I detached it from composed item and again re assign it to another one. Then that item still appear in the combo box.

Any suggestion?

Here is data set 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7dKV.jpg

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  And what does `Type` have to do with the question?  It is not mentioned in the rest of the question anywhere.

Comment: I have snapshot. But I cant upload. My reputation points lower than 10. 

Comment: I put a link to snap shot. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Items` that are not in *any* undetached composed items, then I'm thinking `not exists`:

```
select i.*, t.TypeName
from Item as i INNER JOIN
     Type as t
     on t.TYPEID = i.TYPE
where not exists (select 1
                  from ComposedIITem ci
                  where i.itemid = ci.itemid and
                        ci.detacheddate is null
                 );
```

Comment: I tried your sql. But problem still be there. Item 1and 2 shouldnt be there. Here is snaps.           https://imgur.com/                                   a/kpLGCVN

Comment: @ManojMadushantha . . . I think the `null` comparison was inverted.

Comment: You are right.  Its working. Thanks! For your valuable time.